# Value in between given percentiles

Tags: statistics, percentile

If I have a set of data such as 3500,4500,5700,7100 that represent the 25th, 50th, 75th, the 90th percentile how would I go about finding a percentile in between two of the given points? For instance, how do I find the best approximation of the 35th percentile? N = 3000

THANK YOU!

Comment: I don't think that you can do this without assuming a distribution of your data.  Can you assume a Gaussian or a Poisson distribution?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to interpolate the distribution between the given points, which is difficult if you know nothing about the underlying distribution of your data. And especially since you only have 4 points to work with.

If you assume that the distribution is fairly smooth, then the best you're likely to do is just apply a linear interpolation - that is, draw a straight line between the two points and work out the position of the point between them.

For example, if I wanted to estimate the 4th decile, and hence the 40th percentile, I'd be looking for a point between the 25th and 50th percentiles. The line that joins (.25, 3500) and (.5, 4500) is q = 2500 + 4000p, so for p = .4 we have q = 4100.